# rescan SCSI Disk Without Reboot

Tags: hard-drive, scsi

I installed/added 2 new disks on VMware.

I executed this command and didn't detect any new disks:

```
ls /sys/class/scsi_host/ | while read host ; do echo "- - -" > /sys/class/scsi_host/$host/scan ; done
```

Is there other way to rescan vmw_pvscsi devices?

---

```
 ./lsscsi -s
[0:0:0:0]    cd/dvd  NECVMWar VMware IDE CDR00 1.00  /dev/sr0        -
[2:0:0:0]    disk    VMware   Virtual disk     1.0   /dev/sda   32.2GB
[2:0:1:0]    disk    VMware   Virtual disk     1.0   /dev/sdb    107GB
[3:0:0:0]    disk    VMware   Virtual disk     1.0   /dev/sdc    107GB
[3:0:1:0]    disk    VMware   Virtual disk     1.0   /dev/sdd    214GB
[3:0:2:0]    disk    VMware   Virtual disk     1.0   /dev/sde   53.6GB
[3:0:3:0]    disk    VMware   Virtual disk     1.0   /dev/sdf   53.6GB
[3:0:4:0]    disk    VMware   Virtual disk     1.0   /dev/sdg    161GB
```

Answer (score 7):

The devices should show up automatically in Linux under VMware. Check the output of `dmesg|tail`.

If you've changed the *size* of the devices, you can rescan/recognize this with...

`echo 1 > /sys/class/scsi_disk/0\:0\:0\:0/device/rescan`, where you substitute the SCSI disk ID.

For example:

```
[root@xt /sys/class/scsi_disk]# ls -1
2:0:0:0
2:0:1:0
3:0:0:4
```

Comment: its new disks 2:2 and 2:3
i did that too, with no success :(

Comment: You have to figure it out. You can look at the symbolic links in /sys/block/, but yeah, it's going to be different on every system.

Comment: Sorry, @ewwhite, I deleted the comment before seeing your reply, as a little googling helped me figure out what I needed to do to figure out what SCSI disk ID was what.

Comment: For others, the way I found to find which SCSI disk ID you need to use with the above command is by running the command cat /proc/scsi/scsi (found at http://kiranbjadhav.blogspot.com/2014/10/how-to-find-disk-scsi-id-in-virtual.html).

Answer (score 0):

Try this command.

```
for x in `ls /sys/class/scsi_host/`; do echo "-----$x Scanned-----";echo "- - -">/sys/class/scsi_host/$x/scan; done
```